# Корень слова "врач"

Tags: этимология

Неужели слова "врач" и "врать" однокоренные? (хотя, глядя на многих современных врачей, начинаешь этому верить)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И в самом деле сходство есть. В своем Историко-этимологическом словаре П.Я.Черных предполагает, что слова врач и врать имеют общий индо-европейский корень. Глагол *врачати* - 'вещать, говорить приподнято'. В некоторых славянских языках *врач* - 'колдун, знахарь, прорицатель'.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, современное "врач" восходит к глаголу "врати", у которого было значение  "заговаривать". Ведь лечили заговорами. Однако позже у глагола "врати" стало развиваться производное значение "обманывать", в дальнейшем оно вытеснило исходное, заняв его место.